# How to list all changed files in git commit using Github API

Tags: github, github-api

I want to use the Github API to list all files that were **modified** in a particular commit.  This is for a public repo for which I do not have write permission.

I do not want to get all files **submitted** as a part of that commit because it may (I don't know if this is true or not) contain unchanged files and it certainly contains names of created and deleted files which I specifically do not want in my list.

Worst case, I will be fine if I can get the list of new, modified, deleted files with markers identifying their status so that I filter them after the API call, on the calling side.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a single commit using [`GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits/:sha`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit), and then you can process it using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), for example this will print the modified files as a flat list:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/ENDPOINT | jq -r '.files | .[] | select(.status == "modified") | .filename'
```

There's an important caveat though: this filters the result of the GET query, which contains the entire content of the commit, which could be a lot of data. I don't know if that's a concern to you. I looked for a way to filter the returned fields to avoid using unnecessary bandwidth, but I couldn't find in the API.

You could get more details if you're interested in it, in JSON format, like this:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/ENDPOINT | jq '[.files | .[] | select(.status == "modified")]'
```

This will produce output like this:

```
[
  {
    "sha": "564324525eb706f7cc2756ceef8b82cdfeaf270c",
    "filename": "README.md",
    "status": "modified",
    "additions": 1,
    "deletions": 0,
    "changes": 1,
    "blob_url": "https://github.com/janosgyerik/test1/blob/41885b6c8183de3ab5be02884fdcc37d920e41b9/README.md",
    "raw_url": "https://github.com/janosgyerik/test1/raw/41885b6c8183de3ab5be02884fdcc37d920e41b9/README.md",
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/janosgyerik/test1/contents/README.md?ref=41885b6c8183de3ab5be02884fdcc37d920e41b9",
    "patch": "@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@\n test1\n =====\n nothing special\n+Sat May 13 00:16:02 CEST 2017"
  },
  {
    "sha": "37a26e04e6bdc55935e00f2a092d936240771aca",
    "filename": "index.html",
    "status": "modified",
    "additions": 1,
    "deletions": 0,
    "changes": 1,
    "blob_url": "https://github.com/janosgyerik/test1/blob/41885b6c8183de3ab5be02884fdcc37d920e41b9/index.html",
    "raw_url": "https://github.com/janosgyerik/test1/raw/41885b6c8183de3ab5be02884fdcc37d920e41b9/index.html",
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/janosgyerik/test1/contents/index.html?ref=41885b6c8183de3ab5be02884fdcc37d920e41b9",
    "patch": "@@ -55,3 +55,4 @@\n </div>\n </body>\n </html>\n+"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks much, will check out what effect it has on bandwidth in my case.